# MATLAB reading bit by bit from a binary file

Tags: matlab, wav, binary-data, bit

I am able to successfully read in a .wav file with the following code.

```
[y,Fs,nbits,opts] = wavread('MyFile.wav','native')
```

So I now know from the file the data which is stored in `y`, the `sample rate (Fs)`, `nbits` which is `16` and `'native'` informs me the data is of `uint16` type.

Now I want to read a data value bit by bit. Each data value I already know is made up of 16 bits.

Is there a way for one data value to be read bit by bit. So for a `uint16` data value I would like to read `bit 0` and `bits 1-15`. I would then hope reading bit 0 gives me a value and bits 1-15 gives me a value. Is this possible?

I know of `fread` but I only know how to use this when reading byte by byte.

Comment: Have a look at [Matlab's Bit-Wise Operations](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/bit-wise-operations.html). `bitget` seems to be useful or `bitand` and shifting operations. Depends on what you want to do with the resulting data / how they should be interpreted.

Comment: The most CPUs addresses memory in bytes, which makes a byte the smallest memory unit which can be allocated. In c/c++ you can allocate single bits for particular information in a struct, but the struct does still require its total memory to be a multiple of a byte. Matlab cannot do this as far as I know. Try use bitwise operations to find the first bit instead. For the record, try to use the notation of "least significant bit" (LSB) or "most significant bit" (MSB) instead of first or last bit. This will remove the dependency of endianness when discussing bits.

Comment: I have made a rough work around for what I was after. I just need to experiment with a few ideas. I will be posting an answer in due course. I am grateful for the above comments.

Comment: Please see below my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is always nice when you manage to answer your own question. So here is what I found I could do:

```
[y,Fs,nbits,opts] = wavread('MyFile.wav','native')

Sample = y(1:10,1); %Takes 10 data values
                    %I know I have uint16 data type

%I then take a bit at a time from the data value

Bit_16 = bitget(Sample(:,1),16);
Bit_15 = bitget(Sample(:,1),15);
Bit_14 = bitget(Sample(:,1),14);
and so on . . . 

%I could then produce a matrix from the individual bit values

Matr = [Bit_16,Bit_15,Bit_14,...,];

%Each row of the matrix is now the desired binary number
%Next steps, convert to string and then to a decimal number

Str = num2str(Matr);
15-bit value = bin2dec(Str);
```

You can then do the same above for just 1-bit

Comment: The answer could be improved by adding some functions or loops perhaps, but I am unsure how to do this so any editing to improve the efficiency of the code would be welcomed :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need three lines to do what you are doing as bitget accepts an array of bit positions to get and gives you an array of bits as an output.

```
Bit(14:16) = bitget(Sample(:,1),14:16);
```

Or for bit 14, shift your value to the far right and mask it with the binary 1

```
bitshift(Sample(:,1),-14)
bitand(Sample(:,1),1)
```